# How to make pictures next each other in the center in side html tag

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code

```
<?php
 echo '<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a></p>';
 echo '<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="course_list.php?page=A"><img src="courselist.png"/></a></p>';
?>
```

but when I run it show me this icons(pictures) under each other
like this

```
                                       ICON1  

                                       ICON2
```

How I can make it next each other like this and I want the icons still in the middle of the page.

```
                                   ICON1   ICON2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `p` tag.

```
<?php
 echo '<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="tran.php?page=A"><img src="tran.png"/></a> ';
 echo '<a href="course_list.php?page=A"><img src="courselist.png"/></a></p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by using by using display inline and margin auto atribbutes!

CSS:

```
.imgcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}
#images{
   text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <a href="tran.php?page=A">
        <img class="imgcenter" border="0" alt="Mail" src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/social-networks-instagram-icon.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="course_list.php?page=A">
        <img class="imgcenter" border="0" alt="Facebook" src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/8/178/512/social-networks-instagram-icon.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Running example:
http://jsfiddle.net/X3b5g/389/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the p tag. Or css them style="display: inline"

Meaning:

```
<p style="display:inline">.... rest of code
```

But unless the p tag is needed you can remove it and just use the center tag instead